# Container deploys fine with Docker and docker-compose, fails with kubernetes

Tags: docker, api, kubernetes, docker-compose

I have a docker container with the `Dockerfile` below:

```
FROM python:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

COPY . .

CMD ["uvicorn", "api.app:app", "--port", "5000", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
st", "0.0.0.0"]
```

It runs just fine, however when scheduled a deployment with the manifest:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: premiere-api
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: premiere-api
  replicas: 3
  template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          name: premiere-api
      spec:
        containers:
          - name: premiere-api
            image: docker.io/piotrostr/premiere
            env:
              - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
                valueFrom:
                  secretKeyRef:
                    name: premiere-secrets
                    key: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
                    optional: false
              - name: POSTGRES_USERNAME
                valueFrom:
                  secretKeyRef:
                    name: premiere-secrets
                    key: POSTGRES_USERNAME
                    optional: false
              - name: POSTGRES_HOST
                value: db
            ports:
              - containerPort: 5000
        imagePullSecrets:
          - name: regcred
        restartPolicy: Always
```

I run into an error:

```
exec /usr/local/bin/uvicorn: exec format error
```

This makes the container exit. Running the container with `docker run -it piotrostr/premiere` works, same as using `docker-compose`.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? It happened to me once with `CGO` enabled, however disabling it would make the exec error go away. I tried to build the image with `--platform linux/amd64` explicitly, yet the error above persists.

### Solved

The platform was indeed wrong, solution was to use `amd64/python` image instead of the regular python one.

```
FROM amd64/python:latest
```

In case of using skaffold - one shall make sure the config specificies the platform. Example below.

```yaml
...
build:
  artifacts:
    ...
    docker:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    platforms: ["linux/amd64"]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are building for a different platform (f.e. ARM on a M1 mac or raspberry pi) than the execution environment (f.e. amd64).

Ensure that you either build with the correct target platform, or build multiple images at once so the container runtime can pull the right one for the execution platform.